# How use MethodFilter from django-filter app?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I don't know how to use MethodFilter in django-filter app and I can't find it in the documentation (http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). I need create filter with from and to input for date field. Do you have any idea how I can do this with MethodFilter or another way?

I have some class:

```
class Product(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'created_at]
```

I have field created_at and I want to filter products by created_at (from and to).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the *How to use MethodFilter* part of the question, define a method on your `FilterSet` and assign that as the filter's `action`.

For example to filter by a username you would do something such as:

```
class F(FilterSet):
    username = MethodFilter(action='filter_username')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']

    def filter_username(self, queryset, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            username=value
        )
```

Comment: Can I make the method filter only take booleans? I need to filter whether a field is None (=false) or something else (=true).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you're asking, but to filter your products you can use Q

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset = Products.objects.filter(Q(created_at__gte=from)&Q(created_at__ite=to)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. I don't know how to do it with django-filters. Maybe, I need to use django_filters.RangeFilter class for it.

Comment: Instead of `Products.objects.filter(Q(created_at__gte=from)&Q(created_at__ite=to)` why not just `Products.objects.filter(created_at__gte=from, created_at__lte=to)`

Answer (score 0):

I searched in GitHub and I found this. It works.

```
class DateRangeField(django_filters.fields.RangeField):
    # Django-Filter DateRangeFilter that really accepts a range of dates ;)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.DateField(),
            forms.DateField(),
        )
        forms.MultiValueField.__init__(self, fields, *args, **kwargs)


class DateRangeFilter(django_filters.RangeFilter):
    field_class = DateRangeField
```

Answer (score 0):

for newer versions

```py
created_at = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```